# Does an attack with a ghost touch weapon work normally vs. corporeal opponents?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

So it's a bit of a habit as it seems for my questions to have a really explanatory title. My characters randomly rolled a looted ghost touch weapon last session. I'm a bit confused about the application of the weapon's abilities.

I understand that it removes miss chance vs. incorporeal enemies, but does it give a miss chance vs. corporeal as well? Does it also remove miss chance from concealment or spells like blur, etc.?

Here is the link with the description for reference: [Magic Weapons: Ghost Touch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#ghostTouchWeapon).

Thanx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It works normally against corporeal creatures.

A quote from your Link:

> Essentially, a ghost touch weapon counts as either corporeal or
>   incorporeal at any given time, whichever is more beneficial to the
>   wielder.

Blur or Concealment work like normal. The Ghost Touch Weapon doesn´t interfere there.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it will work against both a corporeal and incorporeal opponent. No miss chances on either. A good item to have when ghost hunting :-)

Remember you must still be able to see your opponent (or know where he is) before you can hit him.